# Variable CURL Response Time

Tags: php, curl

I have a PHP CURL request to an HTTPS site which takes a JSON and request and returns a JSON response. Usually it should not take more than 1 second. But, I have seen that the CURL response time is variable. Sometimes, it takes 4 seconds to respond and sometimes 1.2 seconds. Why is this so and How can I make it faster and process the whole request in less than a second?

Following is the curl response times for the same request in 3 different times..

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://xx.xx.xxx.xx/site/y
    [content_type] => application/json
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 198
    [request_size] => 358
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 20
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 4.213941
    [namelookup_time] => 2.1E-5
    [connect_time] => 0.015284
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.722955
    [size_upload] => 222
    [size_download] => 553
    [speed_download] => 131
    [speed_upload] => 52
    [download_content_length] => 0
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 4.015112
    [redirect_time] => 0
)


Array
(
    [url] => https://xx.xx.xxx.xx/site/y
    [content_type] => application/json
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 198
    [request_size] => 358
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 20
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 1.27581
    [namelookup_time] => 8.3E-5
    [connect_time] => 0.016223
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.104996
    [size_upload] => 222
    [size_download] => 553
    [speed_download] => 433
    [speed_upload] => 174
    [download_content_length] => 0
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 1.273922
    [redirect_time] => 0
)

Array
(
    [url] => https://xx.xx.xxx.xx/site/y
    [content_type] => application/json
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 198
    [request_size] => 358
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 20
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 1.294147
    [namelookup_time] => 7.0E-5
    [connect_time] => 0.025723
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.123456
    [size_upload] => 222
    [size_download] => 553
    [speed_download] => 427
    [speed_upload] => 171
    [download_content_length] => 0
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 1.292577
    [redirect_time] => 0
)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it depend on how fast the site is, and nothing to do with curl?

Comment: This really is a question of making whatever website you're requesting respond faster, rather than curl respond faster.

Comment: Have you tried going to `https://xx.xx.xxx.xx/site/y` with a browser and seeing how long it takes?  Also, does the response data change much?  Caching may be an option if it doesn't.

Comment: What other options are there to retrieve data from an X site instead of using CURL from PHP?

Comment: you could use fopen, file_get_Contents or anything else that will allow you to load an external page (assuming all_url_fopen is enabled). However you going to have varying response times with any of these just as you do with curl. You need to increase the speed of the external page not your client. but even once increased it will vary form request to request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What else is the site doing ? If it has a fixed number of threads (say), and each is busy, then your request will have to wait for a thread to service it. If no threads are busy, then it'll be serviced immediately.

Of course the simplest scenario is given that the server CPU has finite resources and servicing an indeterminate number of requests, there are no service guaranteees.

Comment: This sort of makes sense.. If the site is taking the JSON request, processes it for a second, and returns back the response, why will there be variable curl times. I am not very sure if the site is doing multi-threading.

Answer (score 0):

CURL is a the best way to make HTTP requests in PHP.  It's almost certainly the service that is taking time.  Like waiting in line for a sandwich at the deli.  If the speed of the service is out of your hands, and there are no alternative services you can use, then the best thing to do is to make sure everything else on your page continues to load while the request is being made.